# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i have an error on my Codeigniter :

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\PROJECT_TEMP\evaluasiTIK_HG\application\modules\rss\controllers\feed.php:25)

Filename: controllers/feed.php

Line Number: 21
```

feed.php:

```
<?php
class Feed extends Controller 
{

    function Feed()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->model('posts_model', '', TRUE);
        $this->load->helper('xml');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['encoding'] = 'utf-8';
        $data['feed_name'] = 'DerekAllard.com';
        $data['feed_url'] = 'http://www.syslog-center.net/theme/theme2/syslog.xml';
        $data['page_description'] = 'Code Igniter, PHP, and the World of Web Design';
        $data['page_language'] = 'en-ca';
        $data['creator_email'] = 'Derek Allard is at derek at derekallard dot com';
        $data['posts'] = $this->posts_model->getRecentPosts();
        header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml");
        view('rss/feed', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Anyone can help me. please :)

Comment: What version of CodeIgniter are you using?

Comment: remove the `?>` from the end of feed.php and try again

Comment: Check if your file is saved with UTF-8 BOM, if it is, just remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You have extraneous whitespace after the ?>, remove the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use 1.7.2 version of CodeIgniter? Please modified your code:

find

```
header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml");
view('rss/feed', $data);
```

replace with:

```
$this->output->set_header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml");
$this->load->view('rss/feed', $data));
```